# vim is broken after a brew upgrade

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, macvim

I tried to upgrade vim using `brew upgrade vim` and I cannot make vim works anymore since then.

The error message I get is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried the following:

```
brew uninstall vim
brew cleanup
brew install vim
```

but it did not solve the problem at all.

I also completely removed the content of the `.vimrc` file where some plugings were installed to check for python syntax. 
Again, that did not change the error message I get.

I do not know what I am missing, and I would like to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/43983

Comment: I tried `brew install vim --with-lua --with-client-server --with-tcl` and I do not have the error anymore

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what the cause was?

Edit: nevermind, found it in the link seconds after asking.

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed the issue and it is kinda hack but whatever it works now :)
My error was following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
```

The issue was actually not having version 3.7 located on the path: `/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/`
However I had `3.8` folder there...

So I just made a sym link by doing

```sh
$ ln -s 3.8 3.7
```

And yes I am aware that the fix should be changing reference from `/usr/local/bin/vim` to use 3.8 instead of 3.7 but this works also and I did not have the time to dive in it further.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the similar error but with different library :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/lua/lib/liblua.5.3.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/....../MacOS/Vim   Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6
```

and the workaround give above to add symlink to the available version in the /usr/local/opt/lua/lib directory helped.

Below is what I did:

```
cd /usr/local/opt/lua/lib

$ ls

liblua.5.4.2.dylib  liblua.5.4.dylib    liblua.dylib        liblua5.4.dylib     pkgconfig
```

Above are the versions present in my lib dir and vi was trying to load : /usr/local/opt/lua/lib/**liblua.5.3.dylib**.

Running the below symlink helped and now i can open my vi editor as usual:

ln -s liblua.5.4.dylib liblua.5.3.dylib

Answer (score -1):

The package of `macvim` is a better choise than `vim` in OSX, so please try `brew uninstall macvim`, then `brew install macvim`, it would clean the links related to python and create it again.